# ImageView: Image not filling the element

Tags: android, imageview

I am new to Android (normally Java with Eclipse) and am stuck on a GUI problem. I have ImageViews in a GridLayout. I want the Imageviews to fill the whole element so that they are right next to each other, but there always is a "padding" at the top and bottom of the imageview:
[GUI problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jA1t.jpg)

With scaleType="centerCrop" I was at least able to make the image fill the cell horizontally, but not vertically. Ideally I want the images to be square and touching each other. The whole thing should always fill the screens width, the height should be the same as the width.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
tools:context="binnewies.max.loopsofzen.Game">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/statusText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/testing"
        app:columnCount="10"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
```

...

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tile"
            android:id="@+id/imageView33"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tile"
            android:id="@+id/imageView34"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

...

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tile"
            android:id="@+id/imageView43"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tile"
            android:id="@+id/imageView45"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

...

```
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help, 
Max

Comment: Did you use the search?

Comment: Yes. Actually found a few things, but none of them worked. Unfortunately,  I've already spent hours on this little gui-problem

Comment: Did you try all of the scale types? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: Yes, none of them actually fills the whole thing. Center/Centercrop are the only ones to fill at least the whole width

Comment: I finally figured it out. Apparently I used the wrong way to import images into the project. So Android Studio added a transparent frame to the image. Not the layout was the problem, but the actual image after importing it.